# Tomcat 8.5.45 throws lots of NullPointerException-s after startup but keeps working

Tags: java, tomcat

Recently we have updated Apache Tomcat Server from 8.5.32 to 8.5.45. We have noticed, that Tomcat after startup spams tones of NullPointerException-s into catalina.out, but, Connector keeps working well, it is open and listening:

```
10-Oct-2019 10:48:31.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 13452 ms
10-Oct-2019 10:48:31.247 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Oct-2019 10:48:31.247 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Oct-2019 10:48:31.247 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.recycle(Http11InputBuffer.java:282)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.recycle(Http11Processor.java:1714)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release(AbstractProtocol.java:993)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:961)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Oct-2019 10:48:31.247 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We did check forums, etc... found a suggestion to change `protocol` to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`, but it do not help.
The Connector is configured as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
      protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
      SSLEnabled="true" server=" "
      enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
      acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
      keystoreFile="<keystore>"
      keystorePass="<password>"
      truststoreFile="<truststore>"
      truststorePass="<password>"
      URIEncoding="UTF-8"
      clientAuth="true" xpoweredBy="false" 
      connectionTimeout="60000" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
      allowTrace="false"
      sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
      SSLHonorCipherOrder="on"
      useServerCipherSuitesOrder="true"
      ciphers="SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA..."/>
```

Tomcat and Java version information:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.45
Server built:   Aug 14 2019 22:21:25 UTC
Server number:  8.5.45.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_221-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe your `<Connector>` element now needs a `<SSLHostConfig>` child element? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when working with **Tomcat 8.5** on **Ubuntu 20.04** for [Mifos X](http://mifos.org/) setup.

**Here's my connector**:

```
Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
          port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
          secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
          keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat.keystore"
          keystorePass="GODMYROCK"
          clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
          URIEncoding="UTF-8"
          compression="force"
          compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>
```

But each time I start the application, it threw the error below in the logs:

> SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
> java.lang.NullPointerException

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply changed the connector **protocol** from `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol` to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`. So my connector looked like this thereafter:

```
Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
          port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
          secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
          keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat.keystore"
          keystorePass="GODMYROCK"
          clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
          URIEncoding="UTF-8"
          compression="force"
          compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Thank you very much for this this well-detailed answer. I has the similar problem as Juris. The solution was just chancing the protocol to: 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"